# Перезапуск приложения viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear

Tags: swift

Если работающее приложение завершить, и потом снова запустить, то viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear не срабатывают. Приложение запускается, но как будто зависшее.
Как сделать что бы при перезапуске, срабатывал viewDidLoad

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "завершить приложение"?

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение завершить, то методы цикла для контроллера вызовутся. Они могут не вызываться, если контроллер не показывается. Проверьте здесь ошибку.

Второй вариант - я не правильно понимаю слово завершить. Уточните.

UPD. Проблему решили, автор запускал приложение не через Xcode, а через хоум-скрин.

Comment: <code>import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewDidLoad")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(false)
        print(viewDidAppear)
    }
}</code>
Закрытие, это когда смахиваешь немного вверх, А после второй раз вверх смахиваешь

Comment: Закрытие как здесь описано
https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT201330

Comment: Простите, я не понимаю. Немного вверх? Так приложение завершается или нет? 
Можете мне написать в личку @ivanvorobei

Answer (score 0):

Ты его скорее всего "смахиваешь" в бэкграунд (не выгружая из памяти).
Для отлова таких событий есть хуки

Например, для перехода, в активное состояние

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
       selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), 
       name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
       object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func willEnterForeground() {
   // Здесь делаем, что нужно
}
```